# Change colour of specific histogram bins in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have created the below historgram using the plot function:

```
hist(mst$Total[which(mst$Total<100)], axes = TRUE, ylab = "", xlab = "", main = "", col = "chartreuse4", breaks = tb, freq=TRUE, right = FALSE)
```

The breaks have been specified as the following:

```
tb = c(0,1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100)
```

[image]

I would like to be able to fill specific historgram bins with different colours.

colour one:
[0,1)

colour two:
[1,5)

colour three:
[5,10) [10,15) and [15,20)

colour four:
All bins from [20,25] onwards

How can I do this using r base package graphics?

Many thanks

**Updated with accepted answer:**

Using the accepted answer I was able to create the below plot:

```
range <- c(0, 1, 5, 20, 100)
col <- findInterval(tb, range, all.inside = TRUE)
col[which(col==1)] <- "firebrick1"

col[which(col==2)] <- "gold"
col[which(col==3)] <- "darkolivegreen1"
col[which(col==4)] <- "forestgreen"
hist(mst$Total[which(mst$Total<100)], axes = TRUE, ylab = "", xlab = "", main = "", col = col, breaks = tb, freq=TRUE, right = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: something like `hist(rnorm(1000), col = c(1, 2, 3, 3, rep(4, length(tb)-4)))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we define your color intervals

```
tb <- c(0,1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100)
range <- c(0, 1, 5, 20, 100)
```

and then arrange your breaks

```
col <- findInterval(tb, range, all.inside = TRUE)
col
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

You can then use `col` to color each bin

```
hist(mst$Total[which(mst$Total<100)], axes = TRUE, ylab = "", xlab = "", main = "", col = col, breaks = tb, freq=TRUE, right = FALSE)
```

Unfortunately I can't test it since you provided no data, but this should work.

Comment: That has worked perfectly! Is there a way of specifying the colours rather than getting the defaults? Could I replace the numbers in the col vector with actual colour names?

Comment: Sure, just replace `1 2 3 ...` with your actual color names