# How to partly colorize histogram?

Tags: r, histogram

I've been trying to color specific bins above a defined threshold in the following data frame (df)

```
df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/3En2GWG6", header=T)
```

I've been following this example ([Change colour of specific histogram bins in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086048/change-colour-of-specific-histogram-bins-in-r/37086294)), **but I cannot seem to get this to adapt their suggestions to my data**, so I wanted to ask you here at stackoverflow

I would like all bins with values above 0.100 to be "red", and the rest all to be either no color, or just black (I defined black, but I would prefer no color)

Here is what I tried:

```
col<-(df$consumption>=0.100)
table(col) # I can see 40 points above 100, the rest below

col[which(col=="TRUE")] <- "firebrick1"
col[which(col=="FALSE")] <- "black"

hist(df$consumption, breaks = 1000, xlim = c(0,0.2), col=col,xlab= "Consumption [MG]")
```

However, **the whole** graph is red, and that doesn't make sense..?

In other words, I would like **anything** to the right side of the line below to be red

```
hist(df$consumption, breaks = 1000, xlim = c(0,0.2),xlab= "Consumption [MG]")
abline(v=c(.100), col=c("red"),lty=c(1), lwd=c(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply plot two histograms on top of each other using `add=TRUE` and sub-setting the second.

```
hist(df$consumption, breaks=1000, xlim=c(0,.2),xlab= "Consumption [MG]")
hist(df$consumption[df$consumption > .100], breaks=1000, xlim=c(0,.2), col=2, add=TRUE)

abline(v=.100, col=2, lty=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  I thought of this, and made a new df with only points above 0.100, plotted it and included add=T, but it didn't work (there was an issue with the dimensions(=).  Your method however is quite nice, very easy to understand, and and now I see how you isolated bins >0.100

Answer (score 1):

Here is along the lines of what you were doing. You do not want to count the points above your cutoff, but rather the number of histogram bins above your cutoff.

```r
# store the histogram as an object
h <- hist(df$consumption, breaks = 1000)

# extract out the breaks, and assign a color vector accordingly
cols <- ifelse(h$breaks > 0.1, "firebrick1", "black")

# use the color vector
plot(h, col = cols, xlim=c(0,.2),xlab= "Consumption [MG]")
abline(v=c(.100), col=c("red"),lty=c(1), lwd=c(5))
```

[image]